# How to get @Scheduled to run on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scheduled-tasks

I have successfully deployed my spring boot app using Beanstalk but I noticed that it is not running a @Scheduled event that I have as a part of it.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 * * * *")
public void getProperStudiesInTable() {
    //some code to execute
}
```

I have the jar file deployed on Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1 for the instance. Any advice on how I can get this to run is much appreciated!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I was able to figure out my issue. I needed to ssh into the instance and start the actual server by running

```
java -jar application.jar
```